# Reset scope variable in directive after controller and postLink initialize;

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I create the simple directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('field', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="clickElement()"><input id="{{inputId}}"></div>',
        scope: {
            inputId: '@'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

            if (!$scope.inputId) {
                $scope.inputId = 'abc';
            }

            function logId() {
                console.log($scope.inputId); // 'abc'
                console.log($scope); //$scope.inputId is undefined here (!!!)
            }

            logId();

            $scope.clickElement = function() {
                //$scope.inputId is undefined here
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then I use it without `inputId` field like this:

```
<field></field>
```

When I use directive my $scope.inputId is undefined but not 'abc' as I want.
Why? What can I do to get 'abc' if inputId not specified in directive usage?

P.S. The same situation when the code in `postLink` function.

**EDIT:**

Plank: http://plnkr.co/edit/0mpcbrdUdafCMzATmCYZ?p=preview

Ugly workaround (to show how it must work): http://plnkr.co/edit/G6gxQhgrteJBeNmR7yTX?p=preview

Comment: could you simulate the problem with plunkr/fiddle.?

Comment: @PankajParkar added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default attribute in `compile` and avoid assigning to the scope in the controller.

```
compile: function(element, attrs) {
  if (!attrs.inputId) { attrs.inputId = 'abc'; }
},
```

And remove the code setting a default value.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your plank I would suggest you not to use the direct attribute inputId inside $scope. Instead use properties with '.' object notation as follows:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('field', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="clickElement()"><input id="{{inputId || formObj.inputId}}"></div>',
        scope: {
            inputId: '@'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.formObj = {};
            if (!$scope.formObj.inputId) {
                $scope.formObj.inputId = 'abc';
            }

            function logId() {
                console.log($scope.formObj.inputId); // 'abc'
                console.log($scope); //$scope.inputId is undefined here (!!!)
            }

            logId();

            $scope.clickElement = function(){
              console.log($scope.formObj.inputId);
              alert($scope.formObj.inputId);
                //$scope.inputId is undefined here but must be 'abc'
            }
        }
    }
}).controller("ctrl", function(){});
```

Comment: I want both variants to work. I could set inputId when use directive and could not. If not - then it must be 'abc'. See plank.

Comment: Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. Check my updated answer.